# JSON data not coming from txt file

Tags: javascript, json, tomcat

I created two files index.html and jsontext.txt in a folder named "hello".

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Experiment</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    var a="";
    var b="";
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest;
    var url="hello/jsontext.txt";
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200){
            var values=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            a=values.name;
            b=values.pwd;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=a+" "+b;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and now this is jsontext.txt

```
{"name":"Prasad","pwd":"123"}
```

I moved the folder hello to tomcat webapps folder. started tomcat and then opened the page saying `localhost:8080/hello/index.html`
The page is loading but the values are not coming. How to retrieve data from JSON to javascript.

Sorry if this is so silly. I'm learning coding and even this program is part of it. So kindly help.

**Edit**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Track Page</title>
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAVD0ngfhOFs5rnww7UFyz9rN6UznOIZ1U&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  <script>
  var http=new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url="jsontext.txt";
  var marker;
  var user_lat,user_lng;
  function initMap() {

        http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
            var coordinates=JSON.parse(http.responseText);
            user_lat=coordinates.latitude;
            user_lng=coordinates.longitude;
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: user_lat, lng: user_lng},
            zoom: 8
            });
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                label:'Driver1',
                position: {lat: user_lat, lng: user_lng}
            });
            marker.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
        }
     }
     http.open("GET",url,true);
     http.send();
  }
  function toggleBounce() {
    if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
        marker.setAnimation(null);
      } else {
      marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
  }

  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous. You're putting `a` and `b` into the `innerHTML` before the AJAX response has occurred. You need to do that in the callback function.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4&&xmlhttp.status==200){
        var values=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        a=values.name;
        b=values.pwd;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=a+" "+b;
    }
}
```

Comment: still no luck. Page is blank

Comment: No no. Its working. Thanks. There is error saying "Resource not found" and now I changed the url in my code to `jsontext.txt` replacing `hello/jsontext.txt`. So now its working. Thank you. Using this I have to work on a project. I did this just to understand the scenario. you helped me.

Comment: @Barmer. Is there any other way to make ajax call. I want this call to work for every 3 sec. how to do it?

Comment: Use `setInterval` to run a function periodically.

Comment: now you can. This page is not loading but not displaying anything correctly

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console? That should ALWAYS be the first place you look when you're having JS problems.

Comment: Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number Assertion failed: InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Comment: Okay. I put the values in double quotes. When I remove them. they are working. Fantastic. Sorry for being so silly. And you are genius.